# getBoundingClientRect changed dynamically according to scroll position?

Tags: javascript, html, reactjs, dom

What's wrong with below code? `getBoundingClientRect` value is not always the same, it changed when I fire the function after I've scrolled. Below function only accurate (scrolled to the correct position) if I didn't scroll the page.

```
scrollToTargetAdjusted() {
   const element = document.getElementById('myDiv')
   const dockingElementOffset = 80
   const elementPosition = element.getBoundingClientRect().top
   const offsetPosition = elementPosition - dockingElementOffset

    window.scrollTo({
      top: offsetPosition,
      behavior: 'smooth'
    })
}
```

I didn't use `scrollIntoView` because I need to have an offset.

Comment: may you post your getBoundingClientReact()? If you can't for proprietary reasons we can try to answer w/o it.

Answer (score 0):

According to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/getBoundingClientRect):

> The Element.getBoundingClientRect() method returns the size of an element and its position **relative to the viewport**.
>
> The amount of scrolling that has been done of the viewport area (or any other scrollable element) is taken into account when computing the bounding rectangle. This means that **the rectangle's boundary edges** (top, right, bottom, left) **change their values every time the scrolling position changes** (because their values are relative to the viewport and not absolute).
>
> If you need the bounding rectangle relative to the top-left corner of the document, just add the current scrolling position to the top and left properties (these can be obtained using window.scrollX and window.scrollY) to get a bounding rectangle which is independent from the current scrolling position.

So:

```
window.scrollTo({
  top: offsetPosition +  // based on getBoundingClientRect().top
       window.scrollY,
  behavior: 'smooth'
})
```